# Whats the difference between require a js file that uses "module.exports" and a common js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, gulp

I think It is an easy question, but I didn't find an objective answer.

I'm starting with NodeJS and I don't understand much about how modules work in Node. So, I'm trying to modularize my Gulp tasks, and I tried to use Node module require() with these codes:

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
require('./gulptasks/foo');

gulp.task('default', ['foo'], function() {

});
```

foo.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

  gulp.task('foo', function() {
    console.log('bar');
});
```

**Another way to modularize:**

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var foo = require('./gulptasks/foo')(gulp);

gulp.task('default', ['foo'], function() {

});
```

foo.js:

```
module.exports = function(gulp) {
  gulp.task('foo', function (){
    console.log('bar');
  });
};
```

What's the correct way to modularizing my js files and why (I guess It's something about scope when I'm using module.exports)?

**For curiosity:**

Why does It work:

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
require('./gulptasks/foo')(gulp);

gulp.task('default', ['foo'], function() {

});
```

foo.js:

```
var gulps = require('gulp');

module.exports = function() {
  gulps.task('foo', function (){
    console.log('bar');
  });
};
```

**Obs:**

This code only works when I pass a gulp reference from the gulpfile.js to foo.js, although my module function don't receive a parameter. :

```
require('./gulptasks/foo')(gulp);
```

I've changed the gulp variable name to gulps for testing if It was something about overriding variables.  I don't know how It works, because I don't use the gulp reference from gulpfile.js, and It just work if I pass the gulp from there.

Comment: I guess I am a little confused about what  you are asking exactly.  Are you asking what module.exports does?  Maybe you are getting hung up on this `var gulp = require('gulp');`  `require('./gulptasks/foo')(gulp);`  That second require isn't saving to anything, so you are not really doing anything with it, but calling the function once, and not attaching it to any variable.